# Select taking too long. Need advice for a better performance

Tags: sql-server-2008

Ok, here we go. There's this messy `SELECT` crossing other tables and ordering to get the one desired row. Basically I do the "math" inside the `ORDER BY`.

1 base table.

7 `JOINS` poiting to local tables.

`WHERE` with 2 clauses and a `NOT IN` crossing another table.

You'll see in the code the `ORDER BY` is pretty damn big/ugly, it sums the result of 5 different calculations. I need that result to `order by` those calculations in order to get the worst row-case.

The problem is once I execute the Stored Procedure it takes up to 8 seconds to run. That's kind of non-acceptable. So, I'm starting to check Indexes.

So, I'm looking for advices on how to make this query run faster.
I'm indexing the `WHERE` clauses and the field `LINEA`, Should I index something else? Like the rows Im crossing for the `JOINs`? or should I approach the query differently?

Query:

```
SET @LINEA = (
    SELECT TOP 1
        BOA.LIN
    FROM
        BAND_BA BOA
    LEFT JOIN
        TEL PAR
        ON REPLACE(BOA.Lin,'-','') = SUBSTRING(PAR.Te,2,10)
    LEFT JOIN
        TELP CLP
        ON REPLACE(BOA.Lin,'-','') = SUBSTRING(CLP.Numtel,2,10)
    LEFT JOIN
        CA C
        ON REPLACE(BOA.Lin,'-','') = C.An
    LEFT JOIN
        RE R
        ON REPLACE(BOA.Lin,'-','') = R.Lin
    LEFT JOIN
        PRODUCTOS2 P2
        ON BOA.PRODUCTO = P2.codigo
    LEFT JOIN
        EN 
        ON REPLACE(BOA.Lin,'-','') = EN.G
    LEFT JOIN
        TIP ID
        ON TIPID = ID.ID
    WHERE 
        BOA.EST = 'C' AND
        ID.SE =  'boA' AND 
        BOA.LIN NOT IN (
            SELECT 
                LIN 
            FROM 
                BAN

            )   
    ORDER BY (EN.VALUE + ANT.VALUE + REIT.VAL + C.VALUE + TEL.VALUE

        ) DESC,
```

Comment: can you make an example code on sql fiddle?

Comment: @MichaelDibbets do you know of any data generator or an easy way for me to populate the tables in sql fiddle? since the tables are quite a few with several columns, so inserting data there would take me too long.

Comment: @DanielSh., the first thing I notice is that you are issuing a lot of `REPLACE` statements in the `JOINs`, have you tried running the query without those? The only reason I point that out is because that would have to run for every row in the left hand table that is brought back. You could build a view that selects everything from `BANDEJA_GPYM_BOA` plus the calculated value and then use that view in your `FROM` clause.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll be frank, this is some pretty terrible SQL.  Without seeing all your table structures, advice here will be incomplete.  That being said, please don't post all your table structures because you are already very close to "hire a consultant" territory with this.

1. **All the `REPLACE` logic should be done away with.** If you need to `JOIN` on these fields, then add comparable fields to the tables so you don't need to manipulate the data.  Every single `JOIN` that uses a `REPLACE` or `SUBSTRING` is a table or index scan - those are non-SARGable and a definite anti-pattern.
2. The `ORDER BY` is probably the most convoluted `ORDER BY` I have ever seen.  Some major issues there:

   - Subqueries should all be eliminated and materialized either in the outer query or as variables
   - String manipulation should be eliminated (see item 1 above)

The entire query is basically a code smell.  If you need to write code like this to meet business requirements then you either have a terribly inappropriate design or some other much larger issue in the organization or data.

Comment: +1 @JNK, I asked the same question immediately. Those `REPLACE` statements stood out right away!

Comment: Thanks for the advice JNK, I'll be working on the 2 things you point out. However, What I need to accomplish is to get that particular case    when those calculations happen. I'm trying to have the DB as normalized as possible, so I don't want to pre-calculate beforehand. With that being said, I need those JOINs and calculations. So, besides the 2 points you recommend, is there other "magic" to be done when querying such an amount of tables?

Comment: It's not a problem with the amount of tables, its a problem with mostly string manipulation.  There's not enough data here to give you a definitive answer, and like I said this is way beyond what's appropriate to post on SO, but if  you need to do a `REPLACE` or `SUBSTRING` or other manipulation on **EVERY** field multiple times to get your results, something is seriously wrong with your design.

Comment: Oh, I get the point, it's not just what we do in our querys but also how the info is set on the entire system. Those REPLACE are needed because the info is not formatted the same way across tables. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

One thing that can kill performance is using a lot of LEFT JOINs. To improve performance of LEFT JOIN, you might want to make sure that the column(s) to which you join have an index - that can have a huge impact on performance.

Comment: It won't matter here since almost all the `JOIN`s use functions on both sides of the `JOIN`...

Comment: Well I would suggest that all the left joins could be the root of the problem, and anything at all that could be done to speed them up even a little bit would help. Note than not all left joins use functions on both sides, and they would benefit from an index. Agreed that the functions aren't helping matters, though!